# Java: How do I assign the first value in a for loop to the variable?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a `List` of type `Info` with member fields `String` and `Map<String, Set<String>>`. I need to iterate over the `Set<String>`s. Is it possible for me to assign the first `Set<String>` to a variable and perform operations on itself and the remaining values of each `key`?

I'm new to Java, so this may not be properly articulated.

What I've tried. Given my scenario is understood, is using `entrySet()` correct here or will `info.getInfoMap.values()` suffice?

```
for (Info info : listOfInfo) {

      for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : info.getInfoMap().entrySet()) {

        final Set<String> firstSetValue = entry.getValue();
        Set<String> set = entry.getValue();

        // do something to remaining sets with the first set
        // firstSetValue.equals(set)
        // firstSetValue.containsAll(set)


      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those sets can't be null (and using `var` which is something you pretty much always want to use when iterating over entrySets):

```
Set<String> firstSet = null;

for (Info info : listOfInfo) {
   for (var entry : info.getInfoMap().entrySet()) {
       if (firstSet == null) firstSet = entry.getValue();
       // more here
    }
}
```

your code doesn't work: That firstSetValue = line is executed every loop. Making it `final` changes nothing: Variables in java spring into existence when you declare them and poof away when their 'scope' runs out, and java is scoped to the nearest `{}`. In other words, when the inner for loop loops, a new `firstSetVariable` poofs into existence, and then at the `}` that marks the end of the loop, it poofs away, and then assuming the loop loops once more, poof, there is an entirely new `firstSetVariable`. Thus, they don't 'remember' the first value, as they are entirely new, and marking them `final` makes no difference (it works fine: Their value indeed never changes, so they can be marked final. Instead the entire variable poofs out and back into existence every loop).

Comment: Thank you for the info. firstSet will only be set to null once here, correct? Info is set up so that there are multiple maps per info. Is there a way to reset firstSet to null for every iteration?

Comment: `firstSet = null;` would do it - but if you want it to reset every time, I'd put the decl of `Set<String> firstSet = null;` be inside the first for loop. so, `for (Info info : listOfInfo) { Set<String> firstSet = null; for(....)`. Variables are valid within the nearest {}, and everytime you exit and re-enter the {}, the variable is completely new. Best to scope em to the relevant level, which would be to exist _inside_ the outer for loop, outside the inner one.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to store the variable outside of the loop.  Two approaches that immediately come to mind:

```java
Set<Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entrySet = info.getInfoMap().getEntrySet();
final Set<String> first = entrySet.iterator().next();

for (final Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : entrySet) {
   ...
}
```

or

```java
Set<String> first = null;

for (final Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : info.getInfoMap().getEntrySet()) {
    if (first == null) {
        first = entry.getValue();
    }

    ...
}
```